# Control flow statements. How many years should pass until goal money

Tags: java

I would like to solve this task, but unfortunately, I stopped at this: Maybe I calculated in `int` but should in `double`?

> Peter put money in the bank. The bank increases Peter's deposit by a percent every year. Peter wants to know how many years should pass until his deposit in the bank reaches his goal money.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Scanner myobject = new Scanner(System.in);
        double money = myobject.nextDouble();
        double percent = myobject.nextDouble();
        double goal = myobject.nextDouble();
        int years = -1;
        while (goal >= money) {
            money = money + money * (percent / 100);
            ++years;
        }
        System.out.println(years);
    }
}
```

Test input: 100 15 120

Correct output: 2

Your code output: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making changes as shown below.

```
int years = 0;
while (goal > money) {
    money = money + money * (percent / 100);
    ++years;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you have set years to -1 instead of 0. That is why your code outputs count one less than the expected count. I have updated your code accordingly to make it produce the expected output. Please find it below. Let me know if you have questions.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Stackoverflow_053120 
{
    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        int money = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int percent = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int goal = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

        int years = 0;
        while(money < goal)
        {
            money = (money * (100+percent)) / 100;
            years++;
        }
        System.out.println(years);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but when I enter 1, 100, 8 I get an error. 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 100 8"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
 at Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: This is because you are entering all inputs on the same line. In case the requirement is to get all inputs on the same line, you can try running the modified code which I am adding in another answer. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

you should initilize years to 0 instead of -1 :

```
 int years =0;
```

Comment: which error are you recieving ,I ran the code and it's running fine

Comment: @Thomas Lazer  Need to make two changes 1) years variable need to be initialized with 0. 2) While loop should execute only if the value of money is less than goal amount.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Stackoverflow_053120 
{
    static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    public static void main(String args[]) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter money, percent and goal");
        String input[] = in.readLine().split(" ");
        int money = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
        int percent = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
        int goal = Integer.parseInt(input[2]);

        int years = 0;
        while(money < goal)
        {
            money = (money * (100+percent)) / 100;
            years++;
        }
        System.out.println(years);
    }
}
```